# Bottom Tabs for Xamarin.Android (in Xamarin.forms app)

Tags: tabs, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

You all know regular tabs for Android from Xamarin.forms' TabbedPage is at top.
Because it should be there if it's Native Android app that respect Android UX.

But things are changed now.
Even Google announced new bottom tab bar called "bottom Navigation".
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar
Many major apps're using bottom tab bar.

But I can't use new Bottom Navigation. 
Because my app is base on Xamarin.forms and uses TabbedPage from forms.
It's going to be more complicated if I try to use bottom Navigation.

(I'm making iOS app from forms too)

So Best approach would be moving native Tabs to bottom.

So I found this. (maybe old)
http://envyandroid.com/align-tabhost-at-bottom/

But don't know how to use in Xamarin.Android.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 11):

Had ran the same issue, tried to create a custom TabbedPageRenderer from the code present at GitHub but no luck due to several classes and interfaces scoped as internal. Found a solution, a hacky one though, but seems to work fine in our case.

Simply created a new BottomTabbedPage inheriting from TabbedPage so you can link a new Renderer for Android, then create a new Renderer as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BottomTabbedPage), typeof(BottomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace My.XForms.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class BottomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            InvertLayoutThroughScale();

            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }

        private void InvertLayoutThroughScale()
        {
            ViewGroup.ScaleY = -1;

            TabLayout tabLayout = null;
            ViewPager viewPager = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; ++i)
            {
                Android.Views.View view = (Android.Views.View)GetChildAt(i);
                if (view is TabLayout) tabLayout = (TabLayout)view;
                else if (view is ViewPager) viewPager = (ViewPager)view;
            }

            tabLayout.ScaleY = viewPager.ScaleY = -1;
            viewPager.SetPadding(0, -tabLayout.MeasuredHeight, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Just scaling the page layout and then scaling the children again doesn't make the trick because the original TabbedPageRenderer pads the ViewPager to not to overlap with the TabLayout, so your contained pages would appear with a starting gap so inserting the negative padding fixes that.

Not an ideal solution, just works, but at least you don't run through a full TabbedPage implementation.

Comment: Thanks so much Pablo for codes. I really appreciate. And sorry for not updating the question. Could you please check this out? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/211381#Comment_211381

Comment: Somebody made XF codes with using bottomTab. Everything seems fine. Only problem is that if you push new contentPage, Bottombar will be disappear.

Comment: And I also will try your code. Thanks. I'm really confused and it's so hard to make decision to make app has better UX.

Comment: A workmate of mine tried that route but couldn't get it to work, I joined him to provide some help with the task. Tried all approaches I could think of, such as changing the layout on the renderer overriding OnElementChanged method but no luck neither. I was joking with him about just scaling the page upside-down, and ended hacking the issue this way haha.

Comment: @PabloLópezMartínez However your code is moving tabs at bottom side but leaving space at top side for every page, how can i fix this massive issue

Answer (score 7):

Use [BottomNavigationBarXF](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) NuGet package for Xamarin Forms.

The result: 
[image]

Comment: I never thought it's so difficult just to put the tab bar to bottom.

Comment: I recommend reading this article:
https://xamarindevelopervietnam.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/bottom-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/