# How to make bottom Tab in Android?(Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing on a project using Xamarin.Forms.

In TabbedPage, I would like to display the tab bar at the bottom of the screen in Android.

So we created a CustomRenderer as shown in the sample code on the following page.

[Bottom Tabs for Xamarin.Android (in Xamarin.forms app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446426/bottom-tabs-for-xamarin-android-in-xamarin-forms-app)

In addition, View was created as follows.

```
<BottonTabbedPage xmlns= ...>
    <BottonTabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="tab1">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Tab1Page />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="tab2">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Tab2Page />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="tab3">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Tab3Page />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="tab4">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Tab4Page />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </BottonTabbedPage.Children>
</BottonTabbedPage>
```

I set hide the toolbar on the TabbedPage.
And the toolbar of TabPage1 to TabPage4 was set to display.

As a result, it looks like the image below.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiku7.png)

The tool bar got out of the screen, and the tab bar is floated.
I thought that designation of padding written in the sample code was incorrect and fixed it.

[Bottom Tabs for Xamarin.Android (in Xamarin.forms app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446426/bottom-tabs-for-xamarin-android-in-xamarin-forms-app)

```
// viewPager.SetPadding(0, -tabLayout.MeasuredHeight, 0, 0);
viewPager.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

As a result, the toolbar was displayed, but the tab bar was not corrected while floating.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQvff.png)

How can I move the tab bar to the bottom of the screen?

I do not want to use the library for move down the tab bar.
Just want to move the tab bar down by just modifying the CustomRenderer.

Comment: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF

Comment: No, I don't want to use such library. so my boss not allowed it.

Comment: Any good idea ...?

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem?

Comment: OK, Since I'm working from now, I will post as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml.CS(code behind) file you can call on the following line to put your tabs at the bottom of the page.

```
On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(value: ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
```

Below is my implementation

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

namespace Social.Mobile.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
            On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(value: ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**XAML** 
`<TabbedPage android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" ...`

**C#** 
`On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(value: ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);`
 in the constructor.